# bootstrap image carousel does not work in angular

Tags: javascript, html, angular, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

The first image of the carousel appears in my page, however the buttons do not work and neither does the images move. I have tried using different types of bootstrap carousel but to no avail. I saw some answers which suggested to add jQuery and Bootstrap links to the top, so i tried that but didn't work either.

home.component.html

```
<header>
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    


    <div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
        <ol class="carousel-indicators">
            <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
            <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="1"></li>
            <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="2"></li>
        </ol>
        <div class="carousel-inner">
            <div class="carousel-item active">
                <img class="d-block w-100" src="https://placeimg.com/1080/500/animals" alt="First slide">
                <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
                    <h5>My Caption Title (1st Image)</h5>
                    <p>The whole caption will only show up if the screen is at least medium size.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="carousel-item">
                <img class="d-block w-100" src="https://placeimg.com/1080/500/arch" alt="Second slide">
            </div>
            <div class="carousel-item">
                <img class="d-block w-100" src="https://placeimg.com/1080/500/nature" alt="Third slide">
            </div>
        </div>
        <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="prev">
            <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
        </a>
        <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="next">
            <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
        </a>
    </div>

</header>
```

index.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500" rel="stylesheet">
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>CastleApp</title>
  <base href="/">

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
  <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
  <app-root></app-root>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bootstrap requires JQuery for this kind of actions. You either need to add jquery in your index.html or add it to `angular-cli.json` or `angular.json` (depending on your version of Angular):

### Approach 1 (Recommended):

Run first this command to install both JQuery and Bootstrap:

```
$ npm install jquery bootstrap --save
```

Then add these lines to `angular-cli.json` or `angular.json` (depending on your version of Angular)

```
"styles": [
    "styles.css",
    "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
  ],
  "scripts": [
    "../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
    "../node_modules/popper.js/dist/popper.min.js",
    "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
  ],
```

### Approach 2 (Not recommended):

Add the needed scripts in your index.html. Be careful though as you'll download these templates each time you reload the page.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500" rel="stylesheet">
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>CastleApp</title>
  <base href="/">

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"> 
<link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous">

</head>
<body>
  <app-root></app-root>
  <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
  <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-OgVRvuATP1z7JjHLkuOU7Xw704+h835Lr+6QL9UvYjZE3Ipu6Tp75j7Bh/kR0JKI" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  
</body>
</html>
```

More information from the [documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/getting-started/introduction/)

Comment: @Harish here is the right answer. this will solve your problem , add popover.js